# Fade Div in using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a container with 3 div's in, when my document is ready id like each element to fade in at different speeds, opacity to go from 0-100 smoothly, is this possible with jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. Can you post your HTML and jQuery that you're using now.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has built in method for animating the opacity of the element: `fadeIn`

You can specify the time of fade in in milliseconds as per your requirement.

Select the required container by its id, class or anything as per your markup and call fadeIn method.

```
$('#div1').fadeIn(500);
$('#div2').fadeIn(1500);
$('#div3').fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Was just about to post this. Here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ZV62v/

Comment: @Liam - Yup, jQuery makes everything really simple!

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#div1').animate({opacity: '0'},'fast');
   $('#div2').animate({opacity: '0'},'slow');
   $('#div3').animate({opacity: '0'},1000);

});
```

i think is that what you whant to do, animating opacity. sorry for the english im brazilian

note: 'fast' and 'slow' can be changed for any miliseconds you want as example on div #3

cheers

Comment: you said u want opacity control so i posted that

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yENB/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div style="background-color: Red; display: none;">
        Red
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: Green; display: none;">
        Green
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: Blue; display: none;">
        Blue
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var count = 1000;

    $("#divContainer > div").each(function()
    {
        $(this).fadeIn(count);
        count += 1000;
    });
}
```